# From Query Result to Associative Array Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, associative-array

I'm writing a new class to handle my db and I would really like to implement some custom feature that I usually do while programming.
One of those feature is the possibility to fetch from a query two field, in something like this:

```
SELECT brandId,brandName FROM Brands;
```

And has a result an associative array indexed as my `brandId` and with value `brandName`.

This is what i tried so far but the application seems to get stuck and be unable to produce any error message, just finishless loading

```
function getColHash($query){
    $output = array();
    while ($result = $this->query($query)->result()) {
        $output[$result[0]] = $result[1];

    }
    return $output;
  }
```

Some hint would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result = $this->query($query)->result();` executes the query and fetches all the results into `$result`. As long as the query returns any rows, executing that in a while loop condition like that will be infinite.

You can get the results first and then iterate them to generate your output. Also, [it looks like `result()` returns an array of objects](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-arrays), so you probably want `result_array()` instead.

```
$results = $this->query($query)->result_array();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $output[$result[0]] = $result[1];
}
```

I'm not sure if Codeigniter returns result arrays with numerical indexes as well as string ones, so you may need to set `$result = array_values($result)` before you can refer to `$result[0]` and `$result[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use :

`$result = $this->db->query($query);`

and then do:

```
foreach ($result->result() as $row) {
   echo $row->brandId;
}
```

you can read the documentation for further information about query results.

here the documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: That's the point, I don't want to have to specify what sould be indexed in the array, I just want it take the first part of my query and set it as index

Comment: you could use the result_array() method and use an index, for example "$result[0]" for the brandId